My keyboard layout is always in American on the login screen but switches back to the German keyboard layout after I successfully login
As the title describes. On Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS, the keyboard layout is always the American one when I boot up for the first time. After logging in however, it switches back to the correct one which is the German keyboard layout. I am really not sure what is going on or how I should even try to troubleshoot it. One thing I did was to delete all languages other than German from my OS but that still doesnt work.
Most similar problems appear to be the opposite where the keyboard layout is correct only on the login screen but wrong afterwards. I even tried the fix here but no luck.

possibly related https://askubuntu.com/questions/117013/how-can-i-change-the-language-order-by-command-line-or-text-editor and https://superuser.com/questions/392439/lang-and-language-environment-variable-in-debian-based-systems

None of these talk about the keyboard layout automatically switching for some reason

I finally found an answer for this. Edit this file sudo gnome-text-editor /etc/default/keyboard and set XKBLAYOUT="de"
At least that is what worked for me.
